# Getting table doesnt exist with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This code down here should search database. but I am getting error that my table doesnt exists. And also I want to ask why if I push second time submit button it just jumps to  `else` so it echo `choose at least.... and also all data from database.` Thanks!

Here is php

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                                                   
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM station_tab';
   if (!empty($_POST['station_name']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['zone'])) 
   {
      $query .= 'WHERE station_name' .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['station_name']) . 'AND city' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']) . 'AND zone' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zone']);   
   } elseif (!empty($_POST['station_name'])) {
      $query .= 'WHERE station_name' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['station_name']);
   } elseif (!empty($_POST['city'])) {
      $query .= 'WHERE city' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
   } elseif (!empty($_POST['zone'])) {
      $query .= 'WHERE zone' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zone']);
   } else {
   echo "Choose at least one option for search";
   }
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));    
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
    echo '<br/><em>' .$row['station_name'] . '</em>';
    echo '<br/>city: '. $row['city'];  
    echo '<br/> zone: ' .$row['zone'];
    echo '<br/> Long: ' .$row['lon'];
    echo '<br/> Lat: ' . $row['lat'];  
    }    
  }
  }
```

here is error message when I add name of the city to city.

```
Table 'stanice_tab.station_tabwhere' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right database?

Comment: yes I am, because it echos all data from station_tab :)

Comment: So when are you getting the "table does not exists" error?

Comment: I have edited question and added error.

Comment: you must have a equal sign between the field and the value it the where clause $query .= 'WHERE zone = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zone']); - also here: $query = 'SELECT * FROM station_tab '; - and mutch more times

Comment: The error states for itself: "*station_tabwhere*", you have a typo mistake due to concatenation (space is missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your corrected code:

```
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM station_tab '; // note the space at the end
   if (!empty($_POST['station_name']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['zone'])) {
      $query .= ' WHERE station_name = "' .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['station_name']) . '" AND city = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']) . '" AND zone = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zone']).'"'; // note the = signs and the space before each AND 
   } elseif (!empty($_POST['station_name'])) {
      $query .= ' WHERE station_name = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['station_name']).'"'; // note the = sign and the space at the beginning
   } elseif (!empty($_POST['city'])) {
      $query .= ' WHERE city = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']).'"'; // note the = sign and the space at the beginning
   } elseif (!empty($_POST['zone'])) {
      $query .= ' WHERE zone = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zone']).'"'; // note the = sign and the space at the beginning
   } else {
       echo "Choose at least one option for search";
   }
```

Take the habit of `echo`ing your `$query` variable so concatenation does not add any typo mistakes.

Comment: Can I ask why is that space so important? and thank guys I have moved for now. edit now I see why it is important.

Comment: Because concatenation just merges two strings. If you don't add a space, the words will be sticked with each others, resulting in a typo mistake.

Comment: now it echo error `Unknown column 'my input' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Where does `'my input'` comes from?

Comment: `<td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>` this is where I am adding name of the city. So if I add Brno error will be `Unknown column 'Brno' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You need to add the `=` sign in **all** your `$query .= ` statements.

Comment: `$query .== ` like this?

Comment: Just edited my answer with your complete corrected code.

Comment: The error being? What does `var_dump($query);` outputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90699/discussion-between-d4v1d-and-r2d2).

Answer (score 0):

in phpmyadmin select the database and then select your table

and in menu above there is a sql menu. you can use this functionality to construct sql queries or debug when there are errors like this